# Use induction on $n$ to prove that $2n+1<2^n$ for all integers $n≥3$.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Use induction on n to prove that $2n+1<2^n$ for all integers $n\geq 3$.

My attempt: Let $P(n)$ be the statement $2n+1<2^n$.

Base case: Prove that $P(3)$ is true. $LS = 2(3)+1=7$ and $RS=2^3=8$. Since $LS<RS$, $P(3)$ is true.

Inductive Hypothesis: Suppose $P(k)$ is true for some arbitrary integer $k\geq3$, i.e., $2k+1<2^k$ $\Leftrightarrow 2^k>2k+1$ .

Inductive Step: We now show that $P(k+1)$ is true.

So $2^{k+1} = 2^k.2 > (2k+1).2$ by IH

Then where do I go from here?

Comment: It is sufficient to show  $2(2k+1)>2(k+1)+1$

Comment: So $2^{k+1} = 2^k.2 > (2k+1).2$ by IH $=4k+2> 2k+3 \Rightarrow 1$.
So $2^{k+1} = 2.2^k> 2(k+1)+1$. Does this look good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice work, so far. To finish off:

It is enough for you to simply show that on the right-hand side,

$$2(2k+1) = 4k + 2\; >\; 2k + 3 = 2(k+1)+1$$

because  $4k+ 2 > 2k + 3, \;\forall k \geq 1$.

So, putting it all together, we have:

$$2^{k+1} = \;2(2^k) \overset{\text{I.H.}}{\;>\;} 2(2k+1) \;> \;2(k +1) + 1$$

Comment: @amWhyL you have been busy! :-) +1